# approve comments before posting to facebook

Tags: c#, .net, facebook, comments, facebook-social-plugins

I have a website which I am using the comments plugin for.

When someone leaves a comments on my site, this posts the comments on the person facebook timeline as well

What I want to do is actually approve that comments before positing it to the persons timeline

Is this possible if so please help

Thanks

Comment: If you need to approve content before it gets posted, then don't post it right away. Let the user post their message and only after you authorize it, post it to Facebook.

Comment: I understand what you are saying here but my question is how would I do this and what facebook plugin or API would i use. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your comments moderation tool in facebook's setting?

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

Go to the settings and select Change moderation mode so you have to approve each comment before it appears.